# Converting MMM. DD, YY string to date9. in SAS?

Tags: regex, date, sas

Is there a way without regular expressions to convert e.g. `myString = "Dec. 31, 18"` into a integer suitable for `date9.`?

I found a [PDF from lexjansen.com](https://www.lexjansen.com/sesug/2018/SESUG2018_Paper-202_Final_PDF.pdf) which lists many SAS date formats:
[image: Collection of SAS date formats]
To my understanding, I could do something like `myDate = input("21Dec2018",date9.)`, but there is no SAS-format which matches my input string, so I am forced to perform some fancy regular expression first in order to convert `myString` to `date9.`. **Is that correct?**

A suitable regular expression would IMHO be `s/([0-9]{3}). ([0-9]{1,2}), ([0-9]{2})/\2\120\3/`, which collects the 3-letter-month in `\1`, the one-or-two-digit-day in `\2`, and the two-digit-year in `\3` and rearranges it accordingly. **My issue is now how to implement this regex in SAS with the correct escaping?**

#### References

- According to [Informat for MMM-DD-YY](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Informat-for-MMM-DD-YY/td-p/578024) it looks like I do need a regular expresion
- [SAS Date, Time, and Datetime Values](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lrcon/zenid-63.htm) defines the SAS time integers.

Comment: Do all your values have this exact pattern?

Comment: @draycut: Do youe mean whether all my input dates are following the pattern `MMM. DD, YY`? Well, kind of. The string is either `MMM. D, YY` or `MMM. DD, YY`, so I cannot use some kind of substring-construct.

Comment: Look here https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2019/07/03/create-custom-informat-sas.html

Comment: Use SCAN() not SUBSTR().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression are rarely worth the effort for such simple conversion. Just use SCAN().

```
data test;
  input datestr $20. ;
  date=input(cats(scan(datestr,2,'. ,')
                 ,scan(datestr,1,'. ,')
                 ,scan(datestr,2,','))
            ,date9.)
  ;
  format date date9.;
  put (_all_) (=);
cards;
Jan. 1,2020
;
```

Results:

```
datestr=Jan. 1,2020 date=01JAN2020
```

Comment: If they sometimes spell out the full month then you might need to add substrn() call. `substrn(scan(datestr,2,'. ,'),1,3)`

Comment: I am now testing, and I guess, there are some typos in your code at `'. ,'`. Also: How would I do that within a let-statement?

Comment: Why would you want to put that string into a macro variable? Why would you want to change the list of delimiters being used to scan the string? Why would you want to do anything with macro variables for this issue?

Comment: My bad, I just understood, that `', .'` is the list of *all* delimiters. I guess, my brain is so used to unix RegExes...

Comment: About the use of macro variables: Well, the style of SAS code I inherited is full of macro variables which are being manipulated :-/

Comment: Use a data step to get the date from the string and then use CALL SYMPUTX() to generate the macro variable(s) with the strings you need. Much easier to debug for this type of complex manipulation than trying to work with data in macro variables.

Answer (score 2):

I think the technique described in the first example from this paper will be useful.

https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/245-2012.pdf